# Making a Point Light follow a cube (Unity)

Tags: unity, lighting

I'm trying to have a point light positioned directly above a cube follow wherever the cube goes. However, it doesn't move at all. This is my code for the light:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SpotlightController : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start() {

}

void OnGUI(){
    GUI.Label(new Rect(20,50,500,20), "(" + transform.position.x.ToString() + ", " + transform.position.y.ToString() + ", " + transform.position.z + ")");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update() {
    GameObject cube = GameObject.Find("Cube");
    float xlocation = cube.transform.position.x;
    float zlocation = cube.transform.position.z;

    transform.TransformPoint(new Vector3(xlocation,transform.position.y, zlocation) * Time.smoothDeltaTime);
    //transform.Translate(new Vector3(xlocation, 0, zlocation));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested code, but I think it should be as simple as this:

```
void Update() {
    GameObject cube = GameObject.Find("Cube");
    transform.position = cube.transform.position;
}
```

Comment: I do believe this makes the light go inside the cube, instead of being above it.

Comment: Yup. You can build a new Vector3 out of the cube's transform.position, increment the y value, and then assign the modified vector back to the light's transform.position.

Comment: If you really, really must use GameObject.Find (and you probably don't), then GameObject.Find(string) should be cached to a variable inside Start() and Update() should use the variable.

Comment: Yeah, this code is not supposed to be optimal, but is showing how to make the original poster's code work in the simplest way. He might have a good reason for looking up the target each frame (but probably not!) Bit harsh to get a downvote though - the answer here is useful even if it's not optimal!

Comment: Fair point.  My comment really belongs on the OP.  I'd take back the downvote, but it doesn't seem like I can.

Answer (score 7):

You can also do it without code. Attach the point light to your Cube object and set its relative position.

Comment: +1, as a side note: this won't work if the light has got a Rigidbody component. (I once put one on it by accident)